# Rails4 - ERROR Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - path/path/path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello, after running bundle install (or update) today (27-Aug-2015) I received this error:

```
ERROR Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:/_Daten/Ruby/ai/C:/_Daten/Ruby/ai/C:/_Daten/Ruby/ai/C:/_Daten/Ruby/ai/C:/_Daten/Ruby/ai/app/assets/images/cp-points-icon.ico
```

As you can see, the path "C:/_Daten" is repeated 5 times. 
I cannot imagine why and where it happens.
My _form.haml.html looks like this:

```
<%= image_tag 'cp-logo.png', class: "logo", style: "height:18px; width:auto; " %>
```

This happens on my Windows 10 development environment.
My Ubunt15.04 development environment is showing the icons and pictures quite correct.
And now checked on my Win7 development environment. That is bringing up the same issue.

Issue is: for all pics and icons and glyphicons the path is being inserted more than one time. 
This is my code for showing glyphicons:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</i>
```

And the error is like this:

```
ERROR Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:/_Daten/Ruby/ai/C:/_Daten/Ruby/ai/C:/_Daten/Ruby/ai/C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.4.1/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

So my question now is: how can I take control of the path for the glyphicon-file.
Any help from anyone?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot install state\_machines gem in Windows environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110202/cannot-install-state-machines-gem-in-windows-environment)

Comment: That is not fixing my issue. I still get the path/path/... and it is also happening to more icons and pics (independent of that proposed solution)...

Comment: Well, that sucks. You might get a kick out of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12220024/525478. (I'm on an Ubuntu VM, nowadays, when I need to do Rails in Windows)

Comment: It looks like today I got an update for sprockets gem to version 3.3.4. 
<br>
Now the issue with the wrong path has been fixed 
<br>
Icons, images and glyphicons are now displayed. 
<br>

<br>
Solution: update the gem "sprockets" to version 3.3.4
<br>
Thanks, Andi.

Comment: Please consider adding your solution as an answer.

Comment: I got this @rb_sysopen due to some ruby space indentation. Just make sure to check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 02-Sep-2015 the **sprockets** gem has been updated to **version 3.3.4**. 
I checked my app with this version and all seems to be displayed correctly.
There are no more issues with displaying images, icons and glyphicons.
The path is now not added more than needed.

**Solution: Do not use sprockets gem in version 3.3.3 as it is buggy. Update the sprockets gem to 3.3.4.**

This should be the process to install new gems:
**a)** install manually, do not use bundle install, as that is updating all existing gems 
**b)** after checking the newly installed gem, include that into your gemfile with a specific version to ensure no updates will be done in an unattended way.

Hope this helps.
Regards, Andi.